# Past sentence and use two verbs frequently

Tags: grammar, verbs, prepositions

Which one is correct?
1. I went to do something
Or
2. I went do something
We use "to"  between two verbs in present sentence, but I don't know about past sentence?!
Thanks for helping

Comment: Don't use abbreviations like "sth" here. Respect our time by typing English words. Also you need to show how you've tried to answer this yourself.

Comment: Ok thanks for your mention. I didn't know this thing.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a construction is not available in all tenses, but if it is available, it is nearly always the same construction whatever the tense.

So:

> I'm going to do something.
>
> I went to do something.
>
> I had gone to do something.

Comment: Thanks for your good answer.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the *to*. That's not "two verbs in present" but one tensed construction (*go* or *went*) and one infinitive (*to do ...*) as its complement. The idiom requires that the complement be cast as a marked infinitive, regardless of the construction used for *GO*—see Colin Fine's [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/517925/24489).

Similarly, *went doing ...* presents a tensed verb with a gerund-participle—not a "present progressive" *be carolling*—as its complement.

> We go caroling on Christmas Eve.
>   We went caroling on Christmas Eve.
>   We have often gone caroling on Christmas Eve.

Comment: Thanks for your good answer.